# How to call both next and error on RxJS Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, graphql, observable

If you have an API (like GraphQL) that allows for graceful failures where both `data` and `error` is returned, is there a way to call both the happy and the error path of an Observable.

**Service:**

```
public fetchData: Observable<any> {
    return myApi.fetch().pipe(map(result => {
        if (result.data) {
            // call happy path here
        }   
        if (result.error) {
            // call error path (as well) here
        } 
    }));
}
```

**Caller:**

```
myService.fetchData().subscribe(
    next => {
        // this is called
    }, error => { 
        // as well as this
    });
```

Is there a neat way to pipe / map the result and call both callback functions?

Comment: The state can't be both error'd and not error'd? It's not clear what your after here to me

Comment: What if it is a partial result?

Comment: Since the error is silenced in the original observable, it has to remain that way. Just return the `result` and handle both situations inside the `next` callback.

Comment: I know I _can_ handle the situation and there are alternative solutions, however the question is, is it possible to simply call both callback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `fetchData` func in an `Observable`.

**Service:**

```
public fetchData: Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        myApi.fetch().subscribe(
            result => {
                observer.next(result.data); // call happy path here
                if (result.error) {
                    observer.error(result.error); // call error path (as well) here
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

> [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-next-n-error?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to get a value you back to your caller from your fetch when the API returns an error. You could try something like this

```
public fetchData: Observable<successObject | boolean> {
  return myApi.fetch().pipe(
    map(result => {
      if (result.data) {
        // call happy path here
      }   
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      // catch API errors here and return false
      return of(false);
    })
  );
}
```

All error responses will be caught by the catchError and then Observable will be returned. Then in your caller you can do something like this

```
myService.fetchData().subscribe(response => {
  if(!response) {
    // error state
  }
  // success state
});
```